# Porting OpenGL application to NDK. Shaders effects look different

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es, android-ndk

I've written an application in OpenGL (not-fixed pipeline).
I've ported the application to Android using NDK and there's a few problems. Everything is darker, and some objects don't show as they should.

**Windows**

[image: Windows]

**Android**

[image: NDK]
<sub>(source: [vvcap.net](http://vvcap.net/db/KhD0q9XHJc_q5vFsda10.png))</sub>

1. The teapot on the right is black and has some strange reflections.
2. Lower half of the flying ball is black
3. Everything is dark
4. Water doesn't look right at all.
5. Teapot with environmental has a pink color.

---

Did anyone have similiar problems while porting to OpenGL Es 2.0 ?
I didn't change anything in the shaders or the code except texture loading format:

```
#ifdef _NDK
    if (IsAlpha)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Width, Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Bits);
    else
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, Width, Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Bits);
#else
    if (IsAlpha)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, Width, Height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Bits);
     else
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, Width, Height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Bits);
#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you change the [internal] format to `RGB` in case of data without an alpha channel on Android? According to your above statement, I assume you didn't change the array holding the values either? If so, it would explain the shift in color values because you have a dataset representing a sequence of 4-component `RGBA` vectors, stuffed into an `RGB` texture. Ergo, you would, for instance, sample an `A` value for the `R` component of the second triplet in the sequence. For the desktop GL version, the same does not apply!

Comment: If isAlpha==false then the texture doesn't have an alpha channel thus  `Bits` is pointing to a structure of data with RGB pixels, not RGBA.

Comment: Besides you can tell that overall structure of textures makes sense. If what you describe happened, everything would be jumbled up.

Comment: Uhm ... I just realized, you pass `BGR` on the desktop and `RGB` on Android. Do preprocess your data accordingly? It would explain the switch of red and blue in the screenshot.

Comment: Wow, I think this must be it. It's stupid of me that I missed it, probably because I didn't educated myself enough on what internal and external formats really are. I'll check this out.

Comment: Yes! It solved it! Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: I believe this question should not have been closed. At least in its present form, it is clear and on topic. BTW, it really answered my immediate problem. Luckily, my reputation allows viewing closed questions; but I bet other users can also benefit from it.

Comment: _a propos_ `#ifdef _NDK`: when you use **ndk-build**, `-DANDROID` is set automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your desktop code path you pass `BGR` as the format to `TexImage2D`, while in you Android code path, you choose `RGB`.

The GL has no way to know what data `Bits` holds and simply constructs `RGBA` values from the data (substituting 1.0 for the `A` component in case of an `RGB` or a `BGR` format.) If you don't preprocess your data to reflect the format, the GL will simply take the `B` component values for the `R` component if you lay out the data for a `RGB` texture.

Correct the format and you'll be fine.

Comment: Android does not support `GL_BGR` out of the box. Luckily, the texture shader handles the swap perfectly: `vec3 v = texture2D(tex, tCoord); gl_FragColor = vec3(v.b, v.g, v.r);`